# Установка Yii PHP Framework Version 2

Tags: framework, php, yii

Пожалуйста, помогите. Не могу понять, как вообще установить Yii Version 2.
Вот сам Framework:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2

С первой частью было проще, скачал и скинул, куда нужно, далее запустил командную строку - и готово. 
Теперь не понятно, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yii 2** предлагает два способа инсталляции:

1. Используя менеджер зависимостей - [композер](https://getcomposer.org/) (рекомендуется). Для этого достаточно будет запустить следующую команду: `php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.0-beta`
2. Скачивая и распаковывая архив. (Ваш случай). В данном случае ваш проект будет доступен по адресу: localhost/директория проекта**/web**/

[Официальная документация по Yii 2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите здесь: [Установка Yii](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/start-installation.md).

> Вы можете установить Yii двумя способами: используя Composer или скачав архив. Первый способ предпочтительнее так как позволяет установить новые расширения или обновить Yii одной командой.